# Why in "Frozen" the statement "Am I so ready for this change" has an inversion?

Tags: inversion

In the first "Frozen" movie, while the city prepares for the Coronation Day, Anna is singing a song describing how she imagines the new situation she is going to encounter on that day. At some point she sings:

> But wow!
>   Am I so ready for this change!

There is neither a question mark in the subtitles nor in the intonation. Also a question doesn't really make sense here based on the context. Why is here an inversion then? Is it grammatically correct? Does it have any specific meaning? Or is it just an intended "licentia poetica" to keep the rhythm of the song? Is it the case of V2 word order usage as described eg. on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V2_word_order#With_topic_adverbs_and_adverbial_phrases)?

I've tried to find something using Google but all I have found were pages with lyrics. I also can't see any similar question here or on the English Usage page. I looked for inversion but the results were somewhat non-conclusive to me (yet it took me to the aforementioned Wikipedia page).

Comment: To me it looks like an exclamation using the interrogative form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Exclamatives with interrogative form**
>
> We sometimes make an exclamation using interrogative (question) word order:
>
> - ***Have I got news for you!*** Peter and Michaela are getting divorced! (or, less strong: I’ve got news for you!)
> - ***Did I do something stupid last night!***

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/exclamations